Как выводить данные из бд в кастомные блоки qt?

Собрал блок в QT, состоящий из заголовка, двух подзаголовков и 3 кнопок
Хочу, чтобы в зависимости от количества записей в БД, у пользователя было это же количество блоков. Данные для текста должны подтягиваться тоже из БД
Как это можно реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
